# Does Mercy's damage buff affect structures?

Tags: overwatch

Mercy's Caduceus staff has an alt-fire that increases an ally's damage while channeled.

Does this damage buff also extend to structures, such as Torbjörn's turrets or Symmetra's sentries, if their owner is currently receiving the buff? If so, is it global -- that is, is there a maximum range the structures can be from Mercy or her target to receive the buff?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, the buff from the Caduceus does not affect structures, only the damage output from weapons on the hero you are buffing.

This means:

- Tobjorn's turrets are unaffected by the buff
- Symmetra's sentries are unaffected by the buff
- Symmetra's teleporter is unaffected by the buff
- Junkrat's rip tire is unaffected by the buff

You can buff abilities like Bastion's Sentry mode since it counts as his own weapon and not a separate entity.

Comment: I'm guessing Bastion in Sentry mode is still affected?

Comment: Yes, he is not a builder.

Comment: @Nolonar Yeah, because his sentry mode doesn't create a separate object. This is why abilities like Symmetra's turrets and teleporters are unaffected by the buff from Caduceus and only damage from weapons is.

Comment: Steel trap is not affected, but surely concussion mine is?

Comment: What!? The teleporter isn't boosted? I was hoping for some OP damage.

Comment: @dcshannon telefrags confirmed?