# What do damage buffs affect?

Tags: overwatch

In Overwatch, there are several ways to buff the damage dealt by a hero: the alternate fire of Mercy's Caduceus Staff, Ana's Nano Boost, and Orisa's Supercharger.
Are they all governed by the same rules? What can they affect, or not affect?

*This question exists to have a single reference point for the many, many questions that have been asked, instead of having to update each answer individually when game mechanics change*

Comment: Considering how we already have these: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/266769/108003, http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/264496/108003, http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/269542/108003, I'm not sure why you felt the need to ask and answer this question.

Comment: The damage boost isn't exactly a mystery: http://overwatch.gamepedia.com/Mercy, http://overwatch.wikia.com/wiki/Caduceus_Staff, http://wiki.teamliquid.net/overwatch/Mercy

Comment: -1, I'm gonna disagree and say this is a canon example of the wrong way to do a self-answer. A combination of easily available information and stuff that's already been covered.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer That's not the purpose of asking questions. We do not allow "summary" questions. DCShannon posted multiple links to other questions and the overwatch wiki that answers this question. It's a low effort question and can be considered a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All damage buffs work in the same way, affecting the vast majority of weapons and damaging abilities in the game with only a few exceptions.
The power boost is variable, with Mercy boosting damage by 30%, while Ana and Orisa boost damage by 50%.

The only damage sources that cannot be boosted are:

- D.Va's Self-Destruct
- Hanzo's Dragonstrike
- Junkrat's RIP-Tire
- Junkrat's Steel Trap
- Symmetra's turrets
- Torbjorn's turret

### Edge cases

For completion's sake, here's a list of interactions that might not be intuitive at first glance:

- Projectiles such as Pharah's rockets or Junkrat's grenades will deal boosted damage if the hero is buffed upon impact, not launch.
- Genji's Deflected attacks deal damage based solely on Genji's damage buffs, not the original source's. It is not possible to infinitely increase damage by juggling a projectile back and forth between two damage buffed Genji.
- The damage buff is reflected in the circles and skulls for McCree's Deadeye. A McCree that is constantly buffed will reach skull icons faster than a non-buffed McCree, but will revert back to normal damage if the damage buff is removed.
- All damage buffs stack additively with each other, and they all stack multiplicatively with Zenyatta's Orb of Discord.
- Damage buffs do not affect the healing dealt by Ana's Biotic Rifle.

Comment: Don't know if sources are worth adding to this answer, but You can find examples of D.Va Ult being boosted here. [No Boost](https://gfycat.com/SpeedyElegantChrysalis), [Mercy Boost](https://gfycat.com/EsteemedHappygoluckyHake), [Orisia Boost](https://gfycat.com/UnawarePinkHornshark), [Nanoboost](https://gfycat.com/DisguisedColdHalibut).

Answer (score 1):

There are a few rules for damage boosting abilities.

- ***Ana*, *Mercy*, and *Orisa's* damage buffs stack additively** with each other, while ***Zenyatta's* Orb of Discord stacks multiplicatively.**
- **Damage boosts are calculated when damage is dealt.** This means heros must be buffed during detonation for abilities such as *Pharah's* rockets, *Junkrat's* grenades, or *D.Va's* Self-Destruct.
- **Damage buffs have no impact on non-damaging effects** such as [healing](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/286535/181240), freezing, or knockback.
- **Damage boosts of the same type cannot be stacked.** This means there is no benefit to 2 Mercys damage boosting a single hero.
- **Damage over time effects deal boosted damage for as long as the hero is being buffed.** This includes *Widowmaker's* Venom Mine and *Hanzo's* Dragonstrike

---

Here is a list of which abilities can and cannot be damage buffed.

### Buffed when fired (Hitscan/Melee)

- ***Ana's*** Biotic Rifle (scoped)
- ***Bastion's*** Recon and Sentry bullets
- ***D.Va's*** Fusion Cannons
- ***Genji's*** Deflect (hitscan)<sup>1</sup> and Dragonblade
- ***Lucio's*** Sonic Amplifier (secondary)
- ***McCree's*** Peacekeeper Pistol and Deadeye<sup>2</sup> ([Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/Overwatch/comments/4m2fgj/myself_and_some_friends_tested_some_more_mercy/))
- ***Mei's*** Endothermic Blaster (primary)
- ***Reaper's*** Hellfire Shotguns and Death Blossom
- ***Soldier 76's*** Pulse Rifle
- ***Sombra's*** Machine Pistol
- ***Symmetra's*** Photon Beam (primary)
- ***Torbjörn's*** Forge Hammer
- ***Tracer's*** Pulse Pistols
- ***Widowmaker's*** Sniper and Assault Rifle
- ***Winston's*** Tesla Cannon and Primal Rage
- ***Zarya's*** Particle Cannon (primary)
- All character's melee attacks

### Buffed during detonation/impact (Projectiles)

- ***Ana's*** Biotic Rifle (unscoped), Biotic Grenade, and Sleep Dart<sup>3</sup>
- ***Bastion's*** Tank Mode explosives
- ***D.Va's*** Self-Destruct<sup>4</sup> ([Source](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/269468/is-d-vas-ultimate-affected-by-mercys-damage-boost/269472#269472))
- ***Genji's*** Shuriken and Deflect (projectiles)<sup>1</sup> ([Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/Overwatch/comments/4ltlbu/mercys_damage_boost_works_on_almost_everything_as/))
- ***Hanzo's*** Storm Bow, Sonic Arrow, and Scatter Arrow
- ***Junkrat's*** Frag Launcher grenades, Concussion Mine, and Steel Trap ([Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/Overwatch/comments/4m2fgj/myself_and_some_friends_tested_some_more_mercy/))
- ***Lucio's*** Sonic Amplifier (primary)
- ***McCree's*** Flashbang
- ***Mei's***  Endothermic Blaster (secondary)
- ***Orisa's*** Fusion Driver
- ***Pharah's*** Rockets and Rocket Barrage (note increased self damage)
- ***Reinhardt's*** Fire Strike and Earthshatter<sup>5</sup>
- ***Roadhog's***  Scrap Gun (primary/secondary) and Whole Hog
- ***Soldier 76's*** Helix Rockets
- ***Torbjörn's*** Rivet Gun
- ***Tracer's*** Pulse Bomb ([Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/Overwatch/comments/4ltlbu/mercys_damage_boost_works_on_almost_everything_as/d3qi9lf/))
- ***Zarya's*** Particle Cannon (secondary)
- ***Zenyatta's*** Orb of Destruction

### Buffed over time

- ***Hanzo's*** Dragonstrike
- ***Widowmaker's*** Venom Mine ([Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/Overwatch/comments/4ltlbu/mercys_damage_boost_works_on_almost_everything_as/))

### Cannot be buffed

- ***Ana's*** healing from Biotic Rifle or Biotic Grenade ([Source](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/282795/does-mercys-damage-boost-apply-to-anas-healing/286535#286535))
- ***Junkrat's*** RIP-Tire ([Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/Overwatch/comments/4ltlbu/mercys_damage_boost_works_on_almost_everything_as/))
- ***Pharah's*** Concussive Blast
- ***Soldier 76's*** Biotic Field
- ***Symmetra's*** Sentry Turrets ([Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/Overwatch/comments/4ltlbu/mercys_damage_boost_works_on_almost_everything_as/))
- ***Torbjörn's*** Turrets ([Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/Overwatch/comments/4ltlbu/mercys_damage_boost_works_on_almost_everything_as/))

### Unknown

- ***D.Va's*** Call Mech
- ***Mei's*** Blizzard
- ***Zarya's*** Graviton Surge

---

#### Sources

- [Reddit - Mercy's damage boost works on almost everything as long as the boost is applied when the target RECEIVES the damage](https://www.reddit.com/r/Overwatch/comments/4ltlbu/mercys_damage_boost_works_on_almost_everything_as/)
- [Reddit - Myself and some friends tested some more Mercy damage boost myths!](https://www.reddit.com/r/Overwatch/comments/4m2fgj/myself_and_some_friends_tested_some_more_mercy/)
- [[PC] Overwatch Patch Notes – July 19, 2016](https://us.battle.net/forums/en/overwatch/topic/20747185139?page=1#post-4)
- [Overwatch Wikia - Ability (Ranged Abilities)](http://overwatch.wikia.com/wiki/Ability#Ranged_abilties)
- [DanmakuGrazer - What do damage buffs affect?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/272007/181240)
- [What ultimates can be damage boosted by Mercy?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/269542/what-ultimates-can-be-damage-boosted-by-mercy/269652#269652)
- [Does Mercy's damage buff affect structures?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/264496/does-mercys-damage-buff-affect-structures/264504#264504)
- [Is D.Va's ultimate affected by Mercy's damage boost?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/269468/is-d-vas-ultimate-affected-by-mercys-damage-boost/269472#269472)
- [How do Zenyatta and Mercy's damage boosts stack?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/272501/how-do-zenyatta-and-mercys-damage-boosts-stack/272503#272503)

#### See Also

- [What Attacks Can D.Va's Shield Block (or Not Block)?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/309712/181240)
- [What projectiles can Genji deflect?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/309635/181240)
- [What ultimates can be damage boosted by Mercy?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/309643/181240)

#### Notes

*<sup>1</sup>Applied on-fire for hitscan abilities, on-hit for projectiles. Based on Genji's damage buffs. Buffs cannot be stacked with multiple reflects.
 
<sup>2</sup>Killing shots can be made before red circles finish locking on.

<sup>3</sup>Ana's sleep dart does 5 points of damage.

<sup>4</sup>Beam must be on mechless D.Va to boost explosion damage. See [Is D.Va's ultimate affected by Mercy's damage boost?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/269468/is-d-vas-ultimate-affected-by-mercys-damage-boost/269472#269472).

<sup>5</sup>Reinhardt's Earthshatter is not technically a projectile ability, but takes a small amount of time to travel*

Comment: The accepted answer is a community wiki. If you have improvements or corrections, you can just edit that one.