# How do Zenyatta and Mercy's damage boosts stack?

Tags: overwatch

We know that Mercy's damage boost gives +30% of damage, and Zenyatta's orb of discord gives +50%, but what happens if Zenyatta gives the orb of discord debuff to an enemy and Mercy gives damage boost to someone shooting it?

Will that be 50+30=+80%? (the buffs are counted on the bullets/Xor on the enemy and both added)

+30% of 150%=195% of total damage = +95%? (The bullets come with a damage increase of 30% which are applied on someone with a debuff so you get +95%)

+50% of 130%=195 of total damage = +95%? (The bullets come with +30%, do the 130% damage, then the 50% are added so you get +95%)

The differences between the last two options are just about the logistics and not the damage taken (since this is identical).

So the main question is, is that +80% or +95%? The second question isn't really important but still wondering, if it's +95% which boost is the first one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They stack multiplicatively.

From [a Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Overwatch/comments/4m2fgj/myself_and_some_friends_tested_some_more_mercy/), where they did some experiments:

> Orb Of Discord Stacking: Confirmed! Not only that, it stacks multiplicatively! This means that orb of discord's 50% damage increase is multiplied by the 130% damage of the boost! This means that we get a damage multiplier of: 1.3 * 1.5 = 1.95 times the damage! If the orb of discord were additive (like with multiple Mercy beams), it would only be 1.8 times the damage. That's almost DOUBLE the damage! This is pretty powerful stuff!

Comment: Have you an other source that "of course"? It seems more likely to be +95% but can we be an hundred percent sure without testing that blizzard didn't decided it to be not that way? And I can't test myself since you need to be 3 agreeing to test such things

Comment: @T.Nel Added source, didn't really think it was needed since it's pretty self explanatory.

Comment: Thanks. Notice multiples mercy's  boost stacks additively in your source. I wanted to be sure.

Comment: That's the opposite of what I would have assumed, so that source is pretty important. Notably, they found that multiple Zenyatta orbs stack additively. I'm gonna add a quote from the source.

Comment: @DCShannon Mercy buffs outgoing damage. Zenyatta increases incoming damage. It seems pretty obvious to me that they'd stack multiplicatively, but I guess not?

Comment: Considering how many games I've played where things like that stack additively, it's not even remotely obvious.

Comment: @DCShannon We must've had very different experiences with games, I can't think of one where a similar situation is handled differently. But this is getting pretty pointless.

Answer (score -2):

It would be the 95% boost. They always stack on top of each other in overwatch.

Comment: I downvoted this, then decided that was a little harsh. You have no source, and the second sentence is not only vague, but probably incorrect, depending on what you might have meant.