# Are damage boosts capped?

Tags: overwatch

Are damage boosts capped? Damage resistance is capped at 50%, but I'm wondering if damage boost are capped.

If a player is affected by Orisa's Damage Boost, while being damage boosted by Mercy, while under the effects of Nanoboost, are the effects additive or multiplicative, and would they stack together or not?

Comment: Related: [How do Zenyatta and Mercy's damage boosts stack?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/272501/143571)

Comment: Doesn't seem to be concrete evidence, but I've commonly seen that Ana boost does not stack with Orisa boost, but mercy can amp with either of them separately.